# Conecting AWS Lambda to Redshift - Times out after 60 seconds

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-lambda

I created an AWS Lambda function that:

- logs onto Redshift via JDBC URL
- runs a query

Locally, using Node, I can successfully connect to the Redshift instance via JDBC, and execute a query.

```
var conString = "postgresql://USER_NAME:PASSWORD@JDBC_URL”;
var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect(function(err) {   
  if(err) {             
      console.log('could not connect to redshift', err);           
  }             
// omitted due to above error
```

However, when I execute the function on AWS Lambda (where it's wrapped in a [async#waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall) block), AWS Cloudwatch logs tells me that the AWS Lambda function timed out after 60 seconds.

Any ideas on why my function is not able to connect?

Answer (score 2):

I find it's either you open your Redshift security group public to all sources, or none. Because a Lambda function isn't running on a fixed address or even a fixed range of IP addresses, which is completely transparent to users (AKA server-less).

I just saw Amazon announced the new Lambda feature to support VPC yesterday. I guess if we can run a Redshift cluster in a VPC, this could solve the problem.

Comment: this isn't a connection problem, but a timeout during a long query

Comment: @MartijnScheffer a db connection problem often leads to timeout as a result. It's not hard though to verify on the db side if there was any query actually running

Comment: yes but that is not the subject here, he is talking about the AWS lambda timeout, thats how i understand it, however, it could be either a connection failure, or a long query reaching lambda's timeout, its easy to  find out, run a very short query (select count(*) ....) if that works, it's the lambda

Comment: yes its the connection, i was wrong, maybe a IAM problem, roles, access rights ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using serverless-framework v1.5.0, you should add:

`iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
      Resource: '*'
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
        - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
      Resource: 'arn:aws:ec2:${self:provider.region}:*:network-interface/*'`

Also should add all securityGroupIds to Inbounds Rules, like below:
[image: screenshot 2017-01-09 23 02 33]

More info: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/#vpc-configuration

Comment: again, this isnt related to access rights, but due to the one minute timeout