# Connect Redshift and AWS Lambda located in different regions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc

I am trying to connect to my Redshift database (located in **N. Virginia** region) from Lambda function (located in **Ireland** region). But on trying to establish a connection, I am getting timeout error stating:

```
"errorMessage": "2019-10-20T13:34:04.938Z 5ca40421-08a8-4c97-b730-7babde3278af Task timed out after 60.05 seconds"
```

I have closely followed the solution provided to the [AWS Lambda times out connecting to RedShift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44112128/aws-lambda-times-out-connecting-to-redshift) but the main issue is that the solution provided is valid for services located in same VPC (and hence, same region).

On researching further, I came across [Inter-region VPC Peering](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/announcing-support-for-inter-region-vpc-peering/) and followed the guidelines provided in [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html). But after configuring VPC Peering also, I am unable to connect to Redshift

Here are some of the details that I think can be useful for understanding the situation:

1. Redshift cluster is **publicly accessible**, running **port 8192** and has a VPC configured (say VPC1)
2. Lambda function is located in another VPC (say VPC2)
3. There is a VPC Peering connection between VPC1 and VPC2
4. CIDR IPv4 blocks of both VPCs are different and have been added to each other's Route tables (VPC1 has **172.31.0.0/16** range and VPC2 has **10.0.0.0/16** range)
5. IAM Execution role for Lambda function has **Full Access** of Redshift service
6. In VPC1, I have a security group (SG1) which has an inbound rule of *type*: **Redshift**, *protocol*: **TCP**, *port*: **5439** and *source*: **10.0.0.0/16**
7. In VPC2, I am using default security group which has outbound rule of **0.0.0.0/0**
8. In Lambda, I am providing private IP of Redshift (**172.31.x.x**) as hostname and **5439** as port (not 8192!)
9. Lambda function is in NodeJS 8.10 and I am using [node-redshift](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-redshift) package for connecting to Redshift
10. After all this, I have tried accessing Redshift with both public IP as well as through its DNS name (with port 8192)

Kindly help me out in establishing connection between these services.

Comment: "IAM Execution role for Lambda function has Full Access of Redshift service" is probably unnecessary unless you want the Lambda function to create new Redshift servers. You didn't mention the security group rules assigned to the Redshift server, please add that information to your question.

Comment: Have you configured the Lambda function in Ireland region to run in a VPC? If not, then the traffic will be routed over internet and your request will always timeout as you are providing the private IP address.

Comment: @YeshodhanKulkarni Yes, I have configured VPC for the Lambda function as stated above (VPC2)