# How can I connect to my redshift cluster using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, aws-sdk, amazon-redshift

I am trying to connect to one of my Redshift clusters so that I can fetch data from one of the tables there. I am using Node.js for it.

I used the `createCluster()` method and created a cluster, but I cannot seem to find a method to read from/connect to it. The aws docs are rather confusing for me as I am new to the aws environment.

How can I connect to an existing cluster and get some data out of a table in it?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to make the 'node-redshift' module work before I asked this question here. I found out what I was missing out on. I had to have a security group associated with my cluster. There was no option to create a security group in my region (Asia Pacific - Mumbai). I changed the region and was able to create the group, set the appropriate port and IP and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

> npm i node-redshift

you can connect using this npm name node-redshift 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-redshift

OR

regarding the AWS, i think this will help you

[Trying to Connect to Redshift Over AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245904/trying-to-connect-to-redshift-over-aws-lambda)

Comment: I tried using the node-redshift module but it is giving me the "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND" error. Could you tell me what's causing this?

Comment: also, what should I mention in place of 'host'? is it the cluster endpoint?

Comment: i tried with the cluster endpoint. the 'getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND' error is gone, but i don't get any result. it shows timed out after some seconds!

Comment: that means you are requesting for connection and server is not respondig for your connect so that why its showing you the timed out after few seconds , leave a commit below

Comment: could you go through [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bunnyrabbit/57u4Lcxb/1/) code and tell me what's wrong? The `redshiftClient.connect()` is not getting called.

Comment: @RohitMishra yes i will go through your code, but if you error is been solved and only the connect part is giving you the time out than it code structure mistake , i will have a look and i will help you , but can you mark the answer as correct and pls up vote the answer so that if can other come here they can get the solutions too

Comment: i am providing you the example that will help you to understand http://www.digitalbrix.com/blog/?p=86  OR https://github.com/dmanjunath/node-redshift/blob/master/examples/connection_pooling.js,

Comment: thanks bro, but i already saw those articles. do u see any error in my code?

Comment: @RohitMishra i have provide the link in the above commit pls check it and thanks for the vote up , if you feel that link help you, you can mark it as correct answer

Comment: you should remove the connect code as specifiy in link

Answer (score 2):

To those who are using node-redshift, it was working fine with 12.13.1 but was not responding for 14.15.0 LTS.

Maybe you may want to check your Node version once.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to connect AWS-Lambda to Redshift importing 'node-redshift' module into the Lambda Function. The most important thing while creating lambda layer try to make the layer for 'node-redshift' package for version nodejs10.x. I tried adding the layer for nodejs14.x and was struggling to make a connection to Redshift which was not happening. So after changing the version from nodejs14.x to nodejs10.x it worked. Moreover thanks to **Vijender R**, his answer also gave me the direction to change the versioning for working with the 'node-redshift' package.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, the reason - I've updated node.js. After returned it to version 11.1.0, everything works ok.

The solution is to find something instead node-redshift (since it was updated 4 years ago)

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-redshift-data, which seems to be maintained by AWS itself.

Answer (score 0):

I tried making node-redshift work for a long time ... eventually found an alternative solution using pg-promise - https://javaniceday.com/how-to-connect-to-a-redshift-database-from-node-js/

I had to add '?ssl=true' to the connection string in that example, but then my strapi project was finally able to pull in redshift data.